# Как заставить  Intent.createChooser выбрать автоматически?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно вызвать настройки девайса. Напрямую не получается вызвать, получается только показать список всех доступных настроек, а уже от туда запустить нужную (в ручную).

```
 Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

 localIntent.setPackage("com.android.settings");       
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "Choose Settings Panel"));
```

Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы в коде сразу указать, что нужно запустить, например, последний элемент из списка?

Comment: а они могут меняться?

Comment: нет, не могут, окно показывается всегда одно и тоже, и нужно выбрать последний элемент. напрямую не получается обратиться.

Comment: вызывай интент по номеру

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: я просто с createChooser не работал никогда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо получить список активити обрабатывающих ваш `Intent`:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> lri = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Выбрать из них тот который вам нужен (по сути нужный `ResolveInfo`) разрешить относительно `Intent`'а и запустить его

```
Intent newDefaultIntent=pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!